# basic mysql data extraction using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked all over here. Please be patient as I am new to php and mysql.
I got WAMPP installed & seems to be working OK. I created a simple "test" database from phpMyAdmin and "firsttable" in that. I can do a simple connect using example from w3schools, but trying to select & display data I entered only throws back errors.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Connect
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT reference, firstname, lastname, room FROM firsttable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["reference"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "room:" . $row["room"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

First off, I get a parse error on line 17. The one that reads:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

The error says: Trying to get property of non-object.

I tried wrapping the whole php code in  tags and saving it as html, but then it appeared that no row data was ever found.

I am able to use very simple code that connects successfully. I can confirm the database is in there, so is the table, and the contents I added to it.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for testing purposes `var_dump($result);`

Comment: You need to add a database to your connection function.

Comment: _"Trying to get property of non-object."_ This means that `$result` is not an object but you're trying to refer to it as one. If you `var_dump($result)` you'll see what it actually is. See the docs for the `query()` function to learn what possible return values you might get.

Comment: You do not check for any sql errors when you excute your query. That's a huge error. Your query pronably produces an error, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the database when you connect:

```
$database = 'test';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

where `$database` is the name of your database (`test` in this case). MySQL doesn't know which database your table resides in without you telling it.

In addition, you should always include error checking for your database connection (you have two of these, you don't need the last one) as well as any queries. Sans this, you can check your error logs for more information when something fails.

Comment: I made the suggested change above and dropped the last error check, but I get a parse error saying unexpected "," on the $conn line above (the only added "," was the one before " $database);").

Comment: @Alex, Thanks for explaining "var_dump($result);" I just copied the code example from w3schools so I really don't know what $result not being an object or trying to refer to it as one means either; I'm also trying to figure out what mini-Markdown formatting means below.

Comment: @Shadow, I'm confused: you say I don't check for any sql errors, but should. I'm not sure if the answer was Jay's original, or the edit from Fred, but it says I have two error checks & suggests I don't need both & should drop one of them. I'll also check my error logs.